# JQuery check if the inout is required or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML template, I have required set to False for a specific input.

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" required="false" class="product-data form-control" id="description" placeholder="Description" name="description"/>
</div>
```

I want to print the value of required in JQuery.

```
console.log("Value - " + $(this).attr("required"));
```

**Output :**

> Value - required

I want it to print false. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `getAttribute()` :

```
document.getElementById('description').getAttribute('required')
```

Hope this helps.

```js
console.log("Value - " + document.getElementById('description').getAttribute('required'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" required="false" class="product-data form-control" id="description" placeholder="Description" name="description"/>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it return `true`

Comment: Checking length. Doesn't make sense. Also prop doesn;t work.

Answer (score 1):

The `required` attribute specifies that the input field is *required*, It doesn't matter what you have specified as its value. if you want to store arbitrary data then use *data-** prefixed custom attribute.

```js
console.log("Value - " + $('#description').prop("required"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <input type="text" required id="description" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get value of target attribute.

```js
var attr = $("input")[0].getAttribute("required");
console.log("Value - " + attr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" required="false" class="product-data form-control" id="description" placeholder="Description" name="description"/>
</div>
```

Comment: There can be multiple inputs. So $("input")[0] does't make sense.

Comment: @Pattu You want to print attribute value of multiple in console?

Comment: No just that input[0] might not be description.

Comment: @Pattu ZakariaAcharki posted my answer and you marked it. So what is differece between `getElementById()` and `$("input")[0]` that both return one element?